# Replace text backslashes and single quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, symbols, php-5.2

`get_magic_quotes_gpc()` is `0`.

If I use `preg_replace()` with these arrays:

```
$replace[0]=">";
$replace[1]="<";
$replace[2]="&";
$replace[3]='"'; 

$pattern[0]="#&gt;#";
$pattern[1]="#&lt;#";
$pattern[2]="#&amp;#";
$pattern[3]="#&quot;#";

$pass=preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $pass);
```

It works except for backslashes and a single quotes.

I tried this:

```
$replace[5]="\\";
$pattern[5]="/&#92;/";
```

but it fails.

I am using php5.2

Comment: What is the intent of this code? I'm extremely concerned about its application. "Magic quotes" were killed off for a reason: They were an **extremely bad idea**. Is this related to SQL escaping? If so, use **prepared statements with placeholder values** and do not, ever, do this. See [PHP the Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com) for advice on this and other concerns.

Comment: I read somewhere that `mysqli` (and prepared statements) can be used on PHP version 5 or above and using MySQL 4.1.3+.  If your environment doesn't support this, it is certainly time for an upgrade.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars()` will do this for you...

Answer (score 0):

Your patterns may not have worked based on your pattern delimiters clashing with the `#` in the pattern.  Your `$pattern[5]` pattern should be serving you well.  This may have been a simple mistake during your testing.

Here is code that will replace your array of characters using the popular and non-conflicting slash (`/`) as a delimiter:  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/889c7812d2cabe9230dc927f0e403b58ffee88d4))

```
$pattern[0]="/&gt;/";
$pattern[1]="/&lt;/";
$pattern[2]="/&amp;/";
$pattern[3]="/&quot;/";
$pattern[4]="/&#39;/";
$pattern[5]="/&#92;/";

$replace[0]=">";
$replace[1]="<";
$replace[2]="&";
$replace[3]='"';
$replace[4]="'";
$replace[5]="\\";

$pass="Th&#92;is &lt; is &amp; a &gt; sample &quot;string&#39;";
var_export($pass);
echo "\n";
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $pass);
```

Output:

```
'Th&#92;is &lt; is &amp; a &gt; sample &quot;string&#39;'
Th\is < is & a > sample "string'
```